# React native - dispatching action gets me back to first screen, but it shouldnt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I'been having this odd issue for quite a while. Whenever I dispatch any of action from my context API i get send back to the first screen in Stack Navigation (expo react native).
Is there a way to fix this ?

Files:
context.js

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';
export const AppContext = createContext();
```

App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  // GLOBAL STATE
  const [alarms, setAlarms] = useState([]);
  const dispatchAlarmEvent = (actionType, payload) => {
    switch (actionType) {
      case 'ADD_ALARM':
        setAlarms([ ...alarms, payload ]);
        break; // return;
      case 'REMOVE_ALARM':
        setAlarms([...alarms.filter(alarm => alarm.id !== payload.id)]);
        break; // return;
      case 'EDIT_ALARM':
        setAlarms([...alarms.filter(alarm => alarm.id !== payload.id), payload]);
        break; // return;
      default:
       break;  // return;
    }
  };
  const log = (x)=> console.log(x)
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={ { alarms , dispatchAlarmEvent, log} }>
 
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} options={{
            headerShown: false,
            title: 'Start',
          }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Theme.primary },
            headerTintColor: 'rgb(243,243,243)',
            headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold' },
            title: 'Alarms List',
          }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="AddAlarm" component={AddAlarmForm} options={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: Theme.primary },
            headerTintColor: 'rgb(243,243,243)',
            headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold' },
            title: 'Add Alarm',
          }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and example of place where I dispatch action:
Item.js

```js
const AlarmItem = (props) => {
    const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(props.ring);
    const [ expanded, toggleExpanded ] = useBool(false);
    const [ arrowUpyDowny, setArrowUpyDowny ] = useState(faChevronDown);
    const [ height, setHeight ] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
    const { dispatchAlarmEvent } = useContext(AppContext)
    const week = ["Mon.", "Tues.", "Wed.", "Thurs.", "Fri.", "Sat.", "Sun."]
    const toggle = () => {
        const toPos = ( !expanded )? 140 : 0;
        Animated.spring(height, {
            toValue: toPos,
            useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();

        toggleExpanded()
    }

    const deleteItem = () =>{
        console.log( props.id )
        dispatchAlarmEvent('REMOVE_ALARM', { id: props.id });
        Database.remove(props.id)
    }

    useEffect( ()=> {

    }, [isEnabled])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.time}> { props.hours } : { props.minutes } </Text>
                <Switch
                    trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: Theme.primary+'5d' }}
                    thumbColor={isEnabled ?  Theme.primary : "#f4f3f4"}
                    ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                    onValueChange={()=> setIsEnabled(!isEnabled)}
                    value={isEnabled}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}

                />
            </View>
            <View style={[styles.row, { borderTopWidth: 0 }]}>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback
                    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('rgba(255,255,255,1)', true)}
                    onPress={() => deleteItem()}
                    style={{
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{  margin: 10, width: 50, height: 50, background: "red", justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: Theme.primary, borderRadius: 50 }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faTrash } color={'#fff'}/>
                    </View>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback
                    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('rgba(255,255,255,1)', true)}
                    onPress={() => toggle()}
                    style={{
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{  margin: 10, width: 50, height: 50, background: "red", justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: Theme.primary, borderRadius: 50 }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ (!expanded)? faChevronDown: faChevronUp } color={'#fff'}/>
                    </View>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
            </View>
            <Animated.View style={{
                height: height, // animowany styl, tutaj wysokość View
                // backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
            }} >
                {
                    (expanded) && (<View style={styles.unfolded}>
                        {
                            props.days.map( (day,i)=> ( <TouchableNativeFeedback
                                key={i}
                                background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('rgba(255,255,255,1)', true)}
                                onPress={() => alert('xx')}
                                style={{
                                    width: 30,
                                    height: 30,
                                }}
                            >
                                <View style={{  margin: 3, width: 50, height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', color: '#fff', backgroundColor: (day)? Theme.lighter: 'rgba(255,255,255,.3)', borderRadius: 50,  }}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}> { week[i] }  </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableNativeFeedback> ))
                        }
                    </View>)
                }
            </Animated.View>


        </View>
    )
}
```

Please if you have any clues? or perhaps i am doing sth wrong. Thx in advance

Comment: Is there any error or warning at all? The example you gave looks fine, is this the code that give problem?

Comment: totally no error or warnings. Yes, I gave only one component in which i use context but this one is the most important